# Changing the date format of a variable in php

Tags: php

If I've got a variable with the value: `May-2012`, how do I change the format of the variable to `2012-05-01`;

eg:

```
$data1 = 'May-2012';
$data2 = $data1('Y-m-01');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$data2 = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $data1 ) );`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
$data1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("F-Y", 'May-2012');
echo $data1->format("Y-m-d");
echo $data1->format("Y-m-01");
```

Output

```
2012-05-08
2012-05-01
```

Comment: `echo $data1->format("Y-m").'-01';` if OP want's to maintain a `01` for the day vale

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F-Y', 'May-2012');
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```